# Can't add role to user (UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: discord-jda

I can't add a role to a user. This is my code, if i run this i get an UnsupportedOperationException error. "cooldownroleid" is the ID of the role, I want to add to the user.

Code:

```
Role cooldownrole = event.getGuild().getRoleById(cooldownroleid);
event.getMember().getRoles().add(cooldownrole);
```

Stacktrace:

```
> ERROR net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught 
  exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null   
at
> java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055)
> ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Output for "cooldownrole"

```
> R:cooldown(594147714510356500)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list returned by `getRoles()` is unmodifiable. This is because the role add also has to be forwarded to discord through a `RestAction` which is not something available through `List#add`.

The correct approach depends on the version of JDA used. In version 4 the method has been slightly refactored.

**JDA v3**

```java
GuildController controller = guild.getController();
controller.addSingleRoleToMember(member, cooldownrole).queue();
```

Get the `GuildController` and add the role.

**JDA v4**

```java
guild.addRoleToMember(member, cooldownrole).queue();
```

No need to use `GuildController` in version 4 since the methods are now in the Guild interface.